# What is WDM Capture Device and Legacy VFW Capture Device?

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-capture, video-processing, video-encoding

What are the differences between these 2 things WDM Capture Device and Legacy VFW Capture Device?

And one thing I want to know what is a "Legacy VCM/ACM codecs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Model

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_for_Windows

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_legacy_audio_components

In both cases "legacy" stands as opposed to *DirectShow*.